# Getting 404 when using Guzzle POST in Laravel - Works in curl

Tags: arrays, laravel, post, curl, guzzle

ok so i'm playing around guzzle and seems like I can't get POST to work. It works on curl cli but not in laravel guzzle. am I doing something wrong?

Here's my curl (working fine)

```
curl -i -d 'locationID=2&firstname=John&middlename=Dee&lastname=Doe&sourceID=2&typeID=2&email=johndoe@yahoo.com&emailtypeID=2&phone=1234567890&phonetypeID=2' http://api.company.com/v1/members

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 07 May 2015 14:15:25 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5
Cache-Control: no-cache
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdi; 
expires=Thu, 07-May-2015 16:15:26 GMT; 
Max-Age=7200; 
path=/; httponly
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Content-Length: 59
Content-Type: application/json
```

and here's my controller

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

public function postForm(Request $request)
{
    $client = new Client(); 
    $response = $client->post('http://api.company.com/v1/members',
        array(
            'body' => array(
                'firstname' => $firstname,
                'middlename' => $middlename,
                'lastname' => $lastname,
                'locationID' => $locationID,
                'phonetypeID' => $phonetypeID,
                'phone' => $phone,
                'emailtypeID' => $emailtypeID,
                'email' => $email,
                'sourceID' => $sourceID,
                'typeID' => $typeID
            )
        )
    );
    $body = $response->send();
    $content = view('member.create_result')->with('member',json_decode($body, TRUE));
    return Admin::view($content, 'Member Added');
}
```

Error i'm getting

```
Client error response [url] http://api.company.com/v1/members [status code] 404 [reason phrase] Not Found
```

Comment: what does the method and the route definition look like for this route?

Comment: you mean this? The form itself is working and it's outputting the data if I disable the entire guzzle code.

Route::post('/members/add', [
 'as'   => 'members.post',
 'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\MembersController@postForm',
]);

Comment: the MembersController@postForm method would also be nice. Another think I can think of is the Content-Type header not being set correctly in guzzle. Could that cause the issue?

Comment: just edited my post to include the postForm controller

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$body = [
    'firstname' => $firstname,
    'middlename' => $middlename,
    'lastname' => $lastname,
    'locationID' => $locationID,
    'phonetypeID' => $phonetypeID,
    'phone' => $phone,
    'emailtypeID' => $emailtypeID,
    'email' => $email,
    'sourceID' => $sourceID,
    'typeID' => $typeID
]
$options = [
    'body' => $body
];

$request = $client->createRequest('POST', 'http://api.company.com/v1/members', $options);
$response = $client->send($request);
```

Comment: same error, i'm guessing it's because guzzle is sending it as  'content_type' => 'application/json' by default (according to the error). I need to send it via x-www-form-urlencoded. Do you know how can i define that?

Comment: if you want to change the header just add `$options['headers'] = ['Content-Type' => 'x-www-form-urlencoded'];`

Comment: still the same error. kinda wondering, it works on postman with both x-www-form-urlencoded and form-data

Comment: can u post the console network tab screenshot when the request succeeds with postman?

Comment: not really sure how to do that, but i'm successful when posting in postman

Comment: tried catching the error and body seems to be null. is this the problem?

Request {#338 ▼
  -url: Url {#342 ▶}

  -method: "GET"
  -transferOptions: Collection {#340 ▶}
  -headers: array:3 [▶]
  -headerNames: array:3 [▶]
  -body: null
  -protocolVersion: "1.1"
  -emitter: Emitter {#337 ▶}
}

Comment: method is GET, instead of POST, thats definitely a problem

Comment: turns out my problem is just a simple case of trailing slash (/). I was actually posting it as http://api.company.com/v1/members/ instead of just http://api.company.com/v1/members - wasted 18 hours of my life on that trailing slash :P thanks mate

Comment: Hi @DavidAlrdrin, I can't see any difference between both addresses you mentioned. I'm with the same problem. Can you explain it better?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (requests working in Postman and failing using CURL and Guzzle). Turns out the issue was lack of CORS headers. I added them to my routes using this package - https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors
and everything works fine :)

Maybe this will help someone as I've spent way too much time racking my brain over this.